# Looping a bool question and returning to main method

Tags: c#, while-loop, boolean

I'm trying to check an input is valid from a method call.
I then need that method to receive input, confirm its either true or false.
If false it loops and ask for the input again, if true it returns to the Main() method.
I just keeps looping the same console.write line after every input. Not following my 'while' loop.
So I can't tell if its calling the bool method and returning.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    InputFuelType();
    Console.WriteLine("The Fuel Type Is {0}", InputFuelType());
}

public static string InputFuelType()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter A Fuel Type, 3 Characters Starting With An Upper Case Letter Followed By 2 Numbers");
    Console.ReadLine();

    while (!IsValid(InputFuelType()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Is Not A Correct Fuel Type, Please Enter A Correct Fuel Type ");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    
    return InputFuelType(); 
}

public static bool IsValid(string id)
{   
    if (id.Length != 3)
        return false;
    if (!char.IsAscii(id[0]))
        return false;
    if (!char.IsDigit(id[1]) || !char.IsDigit(id[2]))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Console.ReadLine() by itself just waits for an 'enter', it doesn't store the supplied text anywhere - unless you do it yourself by using the returned value

Answer (score 2):

You're recursing (calling `InputFuelType()` from itself) - and it looks to me like your `InputFuelType` seems unsure whether it should be just "obtain some input" or "obtain some input and validate it" (you're using it in both ways). Aside from anything else, you're unconditionally making the method call itself at the end, so that's *never* going to end.

I would restructure it like something like this:

```cs
public static string InputFuelType()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter A Fuel Type, 3 Characters Starting With An Upper Case Letter Followed By 2 Numbers");
    string fuelType = Console.ReadLine();

    while (!IsValid(fuelType))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Is Not A Correct Fuel Type, Please Enter A Correct Fuel Type ");
        fuelType = Console.ReadLine();
    }    
    return fuelType;
}
```

No recursion needed at all. (Marc's approach of only having a single call to `Console.ReadLine` is somewhat more elegant, but possibly harder to understand if you're new to the language.)

Additionally, you're calling the method twice from `Main`, which I suspect you didn't mean to. It should be something like:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string fuelType = InputFuelType();
    Console.WriteLine("The Fuel Type Is {0}", fuelType);
}
```

Finally, your check uses `IsAscii` for the first character - that *doesn't* check that the character is an upper-case letter as per your description.

Comment: yes, so I meant to call, then obtain, then validate the input. I kept having the error come up after my while statement to my return statement as I was returning the () method. But the declaration of the variable in the main = the Inputfueltype() has corrected this. I've changed the IsAscii to IsUpper() which has now fixed this

Answer (score 1):

Your method calls itself, and never stores the entered data anywhere.

Possibly you want something more like:

```
string fuelType;
while (!IsValid(fuelType = Console.ReadLine()))
{
    Console.WriteLine("That is Not A Correct Fuel Type, Please Enter A Correct Fuel Type ");
}
    
return fuelType;
```

(note that this won't work well with "piped" input from files - you must also handle `fuelType` being `null`, and do something like exit - since that's what happens at the EOF condition)

Answer (score 0):

If this is for something of use rather than learning (in this case go with Jon's solution), consider given the user valid selections. In the code presented, a NuGet package [Spectre.Console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spectre.Console/0.48.0) is used to create a menu. Menu items (fuel types) are static but could also be read from a csv or json file.

The model, MenuItem and class MenuOperations should be in separate files or leave as is.

[image]

```cs
internal partial class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MenuItem menuItem = AnsiConsole.Prompt(MenuOperations.MainMenu());
        AnsiConsole.MarkupLine(menuItem.Id > -1
            ? $"Fuel type [cyan]{menuItem.Text}[/] at " +
              $"[cyan]{menuItem.Price:C}[/] Press a key to exit"
            : "[yellow]Nothing selected[/] Press a key to exit");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class MenuItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    // what to display in menu
    public override string ToString() => Text;
}

class MenuOperations
{
    // Style for menu
    private static Style HighLightStyle => 
        new(Color.LightGreen, 
            Color.Black, Decoration.None);
    
    // Create menu with mocked items
    public static SelectionPrompt<MenuItem> MainMenu()
    {
        SelectionPrompt<MenuItem> menu = new()
        {
            HighlightStyle = HighLightStyle
        };

        menu.Title("Select a [B]fuel type[/]");
        menu.AddChoices(MockedItems());

        return menu;
    }
    // For a real app, load items from a file
    public static List<MenuItem> MockedItems()
    {
        return new List<MenuItem>()
        {
            new() { Id = 0,  Text = "A100", Price = 3.99},
            new() { Id = 1,  Text = "B234", Price = 3.45},
            new() { Id = 2,  Text = "X378", Price = 2.99},
            new() { Id = 3,  Text = "E333", Price = 4.23},
            new() { Id = -1, Text = "Exit" },
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes its part of some learning that I am doing. The purpose is to accept any 'fuel type that meets the criteria. It doesn't actually have to exist in real life.